# Kendo UI Grid: select entire column

Tags: kendo-ui

The code below selects the first cell in a grid, but how can I select the entire column (either the first or second column)?

HTML:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
     { field: "name" },
     { field: "age" }
   ],
   dataSource: [
       { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
       { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
   ],
   selectable: "cell"
 });

 var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
 grid.select("td:eq(0)");   // <--- selects the first cell
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
 grid.select("td:eq(" + cell1 + "), td:eq(" + cell2 + "), td:eq(" + cell3 + ")");
```

where cell1, cell2 and cell3 are the indexes of the cells that comprise the column. You need to calculate these indexes depending on the number of columns; kendo counts these cells horizontally.

Comment: But how do I calculate those indexes?

Comment: you need to count horizontally, for example: row 0 col 0 --> 0, row 0 col 1 --> 1, and so on